# ID3v1 Null Byte parsing in python

Tags: python, byte, id3, id3-tag

I am writing a tool to parse ID3 tags from files an edit them in a GUI fashion. Up until now everything is great. However I am trying to remove the null byte terminators when displaying the info and then adding it back when user saves it to preserver the ID3v1 format. However when doing a check for the null terminator I get nothing.

This is the portion of the code related to the handlig of the tag:

```
            if(bytes.decode(check) == "TAG"):
            title = self.__clean(bytes.decode(f.read(30)))
            artist = self.__clean(bytes.decode(f.read(30)))
            album = self.__clean(bytes.decode(f.read(30)))
            year = bytes.decode(f.read(4))
            comment = self.__clean(bytes.decode(f.read(30)))
            tmp_gen = bytes.decode(f.read(1))
            genre = self.__clean(Utils.genreByteToString(tmp_gen))
            return TagV1(title, artist, album, year, comment, genre)
        return None
```

The clean method is here:

```
    def __clean(self, string):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, len(string)):
        w = string[i]
        if(not w.strip()) or b"\00" == w or w == b"00" or w == bytes.decode(b"\00"):
            counter+=1
        else:
            counter = 0
        if(counter == 2):
            return string[0:i-1]
    return string
```

I've tried every possible combination know of null byte. Either `not w` or `not w.split()` I even tried putting it in bytes and then looping thorught that for null byte but still nothing. My counter always stays 0 on the debugger. Also when trying to copy the value from the debugger it appears as this   which is an empty space. In the debugger it appears as an empty square. I would appreciate the input.

Using PyChar 2017 1.4

Comment: [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip)?

Comment: Nevermind rstrip() didn't work. I solved it

Comment: Sorry: you need to use `rstrip('\0')` of course, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: It worked aswell thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the only solution that works is to use
`w == str.decode(b"\00")` or `rstrip("\0")`
as denoted by Marteen

Everything else seems to not work. However there are still some places where it doesn't work. For example the comment in the file I am trying doesn't have null bytes until the last one.

Upon further inspection with a hex editor I have found some odd characters. The comment continues on with the `\20` character in hex until position 29 where a null character is (for denoting it has a track indicator) the next character is a `\01` for the track. Oddly the genre indicator is a `0C` which translates to  (cannot paste it, it's a box with ceros in it).

EDIT: Using the `__clean()` method checking for decoded null terminator aswell as `w.isspace()` seemed to fix the issue in both other cases.

Comment: "The specification asks for all fields to be padded with null character (ASCII 0). However, not all applications respect this (**an example is WinAmp which pads fields with <space>, ASCII 32**)." and "**Genre is a numeric field** which may have one of the following values: ... 12 'Other' ...", more info [here](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm#MPEGTAG) - if unsure *read the standard*.